# How to add Author field to document content type

Tags: document-library, content-type, word, sharepoint-fields

I need to add field Author to MS Word document template for specific content type.
Content type added to document library.

Standard field Author located in list of library fields, but it is absent in list of content type fields.

When I am opening word template to insert field to body of document, I see only content type fields. The field Author can not be found in available fields in Insert menu dialog.

How can I add standard Author field to content type and then insert this field to word template?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Author field is an internal field and is set automatically to the user id of the user creating the document, like it should. 
*It cannot be set by the user as such.*
Try adding it to a list view to see the value.

Comment: I need to add this field to content type, I do not need to change it's value.

Comment: It cannot be added to a content type.. It is already there as a default list field, reserved only for lists. Could you please elaborate more on the purpose if adding it to content type

Comment: OK, I need to insert Author field to ms word template associated with specific content type in some document library. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Please clarify if you are working with the doсsets content type or did you customize the content type yourself?
In the first case, find the required content type and add the required fields to it.
You can for example go to Library Settings => Content Types => Your Content Type => Add "Author" column